# Подключить шрифты и загрузить при сборки их в папку dist

Tags: javascript, webpack

Использую `webpack 4`. Настроил загрузку файлов `.js, .scss, .css`. Но столкнулся с проблемой подключения шрифтов и загруки их в папку `dist/fonts`. Установил `file-loader` и `url-loader` в `webpack.config.js` все подключил, но в папке нет файлов шрифтов и они не подключаются. В чем проблема?

Подключаю так

```
// fonts.scss
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Darkenstone';
      src: url('./Darkenstone.woff') format('woff');
    }
//style.scss    
    body {
      background-color: green;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-family: 'Darkenstone';
    }
```

Мой `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./src/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: "/node_modules/"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            config: {
                                path: "src/js/postcss.config.js"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            config: {
                                path: "src/js/postcss.config.js"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader?name=./src/fonts/[name].[ext]'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css"
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не задали `outputPath`.

```
{
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
    use: [{
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "путь_куда_вам_нужно_положить_шрифты",
        }
    }]
}
```